# How to populate UITableView with Data from Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, core-data

**I created a function wich should save single elements of text the user types in a textField as Strings to a Entity in the CoreData:**

```
@IBAction func tappedAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newExercises = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Exercises", inManagedObjectContext: context ) as NSManagedObject
    newExercises.setValue(textField.text,forKey:"exercises")

    context.save(nil)
}
```

**No I wonder how to load the information back right to populate a tableView Cell with it.**

*In the past I used NSUserDefaults where I could load back a variable an use it without any further code in the functions for displaying them - I just have to call the variables.*

**How does this work while working with CoreData?
I want the data to be displayed after clicking the button and while the View is loading. Every String should be displayed in another Cell using the reuseIdentifier "Cell".**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return exercises.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    ...

    return cell
}
```

*I also would be really thankful for any further informations / links / videos - since I'm new to Swift.*

Comment: Lookup "NSFetchedResultsController" – there is plenty of documentation and tutorials. Also if you create a new "Master-Detail Application" with the "Core Data" option set you'll get sample code for free ...

Comment: this will help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift